# How to find the windows list of updates/KBs that is opted out or not istalled on Win2k3 box

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I have an issue that happening only at one customer site (windows 2003) . I believe this could be because some windows update/KB could be missing at this site.

How to:

a. find the list updates that are not installed on a given win2k3 box?

b. list of KBs that were manually opted out while performing Windows update?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing would be to load IE and to go the Windows Update website.  There should be an option on the left menu to "Review your update history" which will tell you which updates are installed.  If you select "custom" for the update option it will scan the system and make recommendations for updates that haven't been installed.  This will also open the "Restore hidden updates" option on the left which can be used to re-enable updates that have been hidden in the past.

Alternately, you can use the [Baseline Security Analyzer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/cc184923) which will do much of the same for you and point out individual updates that haven't been applied, among other things.